# How to serialize XML having been read with XmlTextReader { Namespaces = false }?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have a `csproj` file I traverse and comment certain node in it. Since I want to avoid specifying namespace all over (the LINQ2XML queries come from my class's consumers, and they don't want to specify namespaces), I set:

```
var xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(_path) {
    Namespaces = false // avoid that hassle...
};
```

However then I cannot output the document:

```
var xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(_path) {
    Namespaces = false // avoid that hassle...
};

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlTextReader, LoadOptions.SetLineInfo | LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
xmlTextReader.Close();

Do_some_stuff_with_doc_like_run_queries_and_comment_certain_node(doc);

var flattenedXmlContent = doc.ToString(); // throws System.Xml.XmlException:
// 'The prefix '' cannot be redefined from '' to 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003' within the same start element tag.'

Console.WriteLine(flattenedXmlContent);
```

`doc.ToString()` throws the exception described in the comment above, I change `doc` or not.

I understand that I removed the namespace, and that's the cause of the problem, but how can I both allow queries to be without namespaces, and keep my capability to serialize it?

Comment: The property Names for XmlTextRead does not remove the namespace.  It says the XmlReader can support namespaces.  Now if you set the option to false and you try to read an xml with namespace you will get an exception.

Comment: @jdweng, I am able to read an xml with namespace (see any `csproj` file). The problem is that I can't `ToString()` it - that's where I get the exception. The main question however is how to avoid all the fuss with namespaces

Comment: Well I can't read my xml with namespaces using your code.  To avoid namespace I usually use Where(x => x.Name.LocalName = "mytagname)